# Apache: Reverse Proxy based on subdomain

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, proxypass

I'm trying to set a reverse proxy by replacing the domain and keeping the subdomain.
What I want to achieve is:

- `abc.example.org` shall be reverse proxied to `abc.hello.dev`
- `xyz.example.org` shall be reverse-proxied to `xyz.hello.dev`

Note: abc, xyz, etc. are completely dynamic.

What I'm currently not getting is the syntax for **ProxyPass** and **ProxyPassReverse**.

Thank you very much,

Cheers
Fritz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
  SetEnvIf Host "^([^.]*).example.org$" SUBDOMAIN=$1
  ProxyPassInterpolateEnv On
  ProxyPass / https://${SUBDOMAIN}.hello.dev/ interpolate
  ProxyPassReverse / https://${SUBDOMAIN}.hello.dev/ interpolate
 </IfModule>
```